# PHP Mail Script only emails one address

Tags: php, email, html-email

I have this PHP script that links in with a CRM, but the email doesn't send to the admin address; it only sends to the email address that the user puts in (their own email address). It does not send to the `ADMIN EMAIL`.

Here's the script. Any help would be great; I didn't write this and I haven't been in the job long!

```
<?php
$parameter = $_GET;
$query = http_build_query($parameter, '', '&');
$url = "CRM Address";
$url .= "?".$query; 

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: FROM EMAIL' . "\r\n" ;

$to = $_GET['Emailaddress'];
$subject = "Thank you";
$message = '

';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$message2 = "";
foreach ($parameter as $k => $s){
    $message2 .= "<p>".$k." : ".$s."</p>";
}   
$to = "ADMIN EMAIL";
$subject2 = "Enquire";
mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers);

if($result){
    header('Location:REDIRECT');
    }
?>
```

Comment: upvoted because this question is valid, on-topic and question is really answerable. No need to down vote when you see a question with poor written code. A poor written question should be downvoted not poor written codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your script, especially this part:

```
$to = "ADMIN EMAIL";
$subject2 = "Enquire";
mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers);
```

You set `$to`, but send the email to `$to2`. Change your script to

```
$to2 = "ADMIN EMAIL"; // fix the variable name
$subject2 = "Enquire";
mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers);
```

This is a good illustration why you:

1. Should use an IDE and a debugger.
2. Should never just use scripts you got from the Internet if you don't understand them.
3. Should use descriptive variable names, not `$foo` and `$foo2`.

Comment: Thank you so much - will learn from this :)

Comment: Will accept when it allows me to